# C# - updating child class from base class

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have a situation where I need to differentiate different "types" of `Customer` objects.

I.e.:

```
public abstract class Customer
{    
    protected Customer(string customerType, string emailAddress, string phoneNUmber)
    {
        Type = customerType;
        ContactEmail = emailAddress;
        ContactPhone = phoneNUmber;
    }

    public string ContactEmail { get; private set; }

    public string ContactPhone { get; private set; }
}



internal class CorporateCustomer : Customer
{
    public CorporateCustomer(string customerType, string emailAddress, string phoneNumber, string businessName) : base(customerType, emailAddress, phoneNumber)
    {
        BusinessName = businessName;
    }

    public BusinessName BusinessName { get; private set; }
}


internal class IndividualCustomer : Customer
{
    public IndividualCustomer(string customerType, string emailAddress, string phoneNumber, string individualName) : base(customerType, emailAddress, phoneNumber)
    {
        IndividualName = individualName;
    }

    public string IndividualName { get; private set; }
}
```

I'm using ASP.NET EF Core and have this in my property configuration:

```
builder
    .HasDiscriminator(x => x.CustomerType)
    .HasValue<CorporateCustomer>("CORPORATE")
    .HasValue<IndividualCustomer>("INDIVIDUAL");
```

So, that the object comes out of the database properly as either an individual customer or a corporate customer.

I'm writing a command handler that wants to update the `Customer` object.

No problem if I want to update `ContactEmailAddress` or `ContactPhoneNumber` or even `BusinessName` or `IndividualName` because the object is of the proper type.

But, if the user wants to change the object from a `CorporateCustomer` to an `IndividualCustomer` or vice versa.  Fundamentally, what I need to accomplish is to change the `CustomerType`, blank out the "Name" field that isn't used and populate the one that is and store it.

I believe this is where `abstract` and/or `virtual` methods come in, but could use a little assistance if possible.

Comment: There is no OOP magic that allows changing a type to a sibling type in C#. You'd have to re-create the object.

Comment: That's not supported by EF Core, though you could execute raw sql. And I don't really see how a company could suddenly transform into an individual.

Comment: Deriving from `Customer` means that objects of type `CorporateCustomer` and `IndividualCustomer` can be treated as if they were of type `Customer`. An `IEnumerable<Customer>` collection can contain both types.  Because `Customer` is `abstract`, an instance of 'just' `Customer` can't be created. An object of `Customer` must be either a CorporateCustomer` or an `IndividualCustomer`. A `virtual` member can be overridden in a derived class. A `public virtual string ContactName { get; }` on `Customer` might be `public override string ContactName { get => IndividualName; }` on `IndividualCustomer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you can't do that. Alternatively I think this is a situation where should ask what the goal is here.

EF does allow you to have this shared mapping, although it doesn't seem like you're getting the best mileage out of it for your situation. Given the that, I think it might be advisable for you to switch to a multi-table solution where you have the shared info in a CUSTOMER table and then join with the other COMPANY_CUSTOMER or INDIVIDUAL_CUSTOMER tables. When you want to perform the switch you can simply drop the values in the table and add an entry into the other table.

This would technically make it possible for a given CUSTOMER to have an entry per type, but with good business rules this could be easily mitigated.

As mentioned before, this is a different solution that gets you to the same end. The direct answer to your question is that you cannot do what you're looking for.

Comment: Or with optional owned types, store the data within the same existing table.

Comment: Between the comments and this answer, it's occurred to me that the real answer is I need to think about the domain model and business case more so than "OOO magic".  1) "how can a company suddenly transform into an individual (or vice versa)" and 2) "what is the goal".  Thanks everyone for the input.